# Numerical Method for Equation System of two depending Equation Systems

Tags: numerics, linear-system

I am searching a solution method for the following equation system of equation systems:

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be an invertible Matrix, $f, b_1, b_2 \in\mathbb{R}^n$ given vectors and $ C_i \in \mathbb{R}$ constants. I am searching for a numerical method to find the solution vectors $x_1, x_2  \in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that

\begin{align}
C_1A x_1 + C_2A x_2 &= C_1b_1 \\
C_3Ax_1 + C_4 Ax_2 &= f + C_3b_1  - C_5 b_2 
\end{align}

I know that I also can write this as a equation system i.e. 
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
C_1 A & C_2 A \\
C_3 A & C_4 A 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 
x_1  \\
x_2
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
0 \\ f
\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} 
C_1 & 0\\ 
C_3 & -C_5
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 
b_1 \\ b_2
\end{pmatrix} 
\end{equation}

I am happy and looking forward getting some suggestions.

Comment: If you combine the right hand side of your second equation. You have your system in a general form: Ax=b. You may then make use of a linear algebra package of your choice to solve the system (matlab / LAPACK etc). Do you have performace problems? Are there any properties of A you could make use of?

Comment: Hi @MPIchael, A is a stiffness matrix resulting from an elliptic BVP i.e. A = B*C*B^T where B are the derivatives of the ansatz functions and C is Youngs Modulus. Of course b_i is a vector of the form B*f_i

Comment: That means that A is sparse, right? In that case any iterative solver should be quite efficient to solve it.